# Solve Java heap space error when adding new values to double Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, memory-management, file-io, memory-leaks

## Context

I have an assignment that is asking me to read a recipe from a text file and manipulate the contents like units of measurement and ingredient quantity's. I have manged to split the recipe into three arraylists, and now have to start converting imperial units to metric. But when I try to multiply and convert the corresponding units I get the Java heap space error. I looked online how to fix this and realized it may have something to do with arraylists leaking memory or using to much space. The issue is I have no clue where this might occur, and have already tried using float lists or integer lists instead of doubles and it still hasn't worked, as I still need to use decimals. I know that the string conversion to ml works, but don't know if the corresponding conversion with numbers does, any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Main {
    /**
     * Prints methods to user
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        servingReader();
        System.out.println(sSize);
        ingrReader();
        System.out.println(ingrList);
        ingrSeperator();
        System.out.println(ingrSeperatorList);
        System.out.println(ingrSeperatorList.get(7));
        divide();
        System.out.println(ingrSeperatorList);
        converter();
        System.out.println(ingrList);
        System.out.print(ingrSeperatorList);
        multiply();
        System.out.print(ingrSeperatorList);
    }//end main

    static int sSize;//int for serving size

    /**
     * Reads text file
     */
    public static void servingReader() throws Exception{

        //recipe read
        File recipe = new File("/home/runner/recipe.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(recipe);

        //loop to find serving size
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String s = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            if(s.equals("SERVING SIZE")){
                sSize = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        sc.close();//scanner closed
    }//servingReader

    static ArrayList<String> ingrList = new ArrayList<>();//ArrayList for ingredients created

    static String scan;

    /**
     * Reads recipe and adds ingredients section to list
     */
    public static void ingrReader() throws Exception{

        //recipe read
        File recipe = new File("/home/runner/recipe.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(recipe);

        //loop to find ingredients section or recipe
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String s = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            //if scanner finds header INGREDIENTS, section added to ingrList
            if(s.equals("INGREDIENTS")){
                while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                    int i = 0;
                    scan = sc.nextLine();
                    ingrList.add(i, scan);
                    i+= 1;
                    //if nothing is found, breaks
                    if(scan.equals("")){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();//scanner closed

        Collections.reverse(ingrList);//reverse method reverses order of elements in ingrList

        int ingr1 = ingrList.size() - 1;
        ingrList.remove(ingr1);

    }//ingrReader

    static ArrayList<Float> ingrSeperatorList = new ArrayList<Float>();//ArrayList for seperated ingredients created

    /**
     * Seperates ingredient quantitys from ingredints list and adds to seperated list
     */
    public static void ingrSeperator(){

        float ingr2 = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <ingrList.size(); i++){
            String split [] = ingrList.get(i).split(" ");
            ingr2 =  Float.parseFloat(split[0]);
            ingrSeperatorList.add(ingr2);

        }
    }//end ingrSeperator


    /**
     * Gets serving size input from user and then adjusts seperated ingredinets accordingly
     */
    public static void divide() throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your serving size: ");//serving size enetered
        int servingSize = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<ingrSeperatorList.size();i++){
            ingrSeperatorList.set(i,ingrSeperatorList.get(i)*servingSize);//origanal quantiys multiplyed by new serving size
        }

        for(int i=0;i<ingrSeperatorList.size();i++){
            ingrSeperatorList.set(i,ingrSeperatorList.get(i)/4);//multiplyed quantitys now didvided by origanal serving size 4
        }
        sc.close();//scanner closed
    }//end divide
```

Problem starts in my converter method:

```
    /**
     * Asks user for choice of units and converts arraylists accorrdingly
     */
    public static void converter() throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
/*
        System.out.print("Use imperial or metric: ");//asks user for imperial or metric
        char choice =  sc.next().charAt(0);

        //if user chooses metric
        if((choice == 'a') || (choice == 'A')){*/

        //convert tbsp to ml
        for(int i = 0; i < ingrList .size(); i++){
            //if ingrList contains tbsp replaced with ml
            if(ingrList.get(i).contains("tbsp")){
                ingrList.set(i,ingrList.get(i).replace("tbsp", "ml"));

                for(int j=0;j<ingrSeperatorList.size();j++){
                    ingrSeperatorList.add(ingrSeperatorList.get(j)*15);

                }
            }
        }

        //convert tbsp to ml
        for(int i = 0; i < ingrList .size(); i++){
            //if ingrList contains cup replaced with ml
            if(ingrList.get(i).contains("cup")){
                ingrList.set(i,ingrList.get(i).replace("cup", "ml"));

                for(int j=0;j<ingrSeperatorList.size();j++){
                    ingrSeperatorList.set(j,ingrSeperatorList.get(j)*250);
                }
            }
        }

        //convert tsp to ml
        for(int i = 0; i < ingrList .size(); i++){
            //if ingrList contains tsp replaced with ml
            if(ingrList.get(i).contains("tsp")){
                ingrList.set(i,ingrList.get(i).replace("tsp", "ml"));

                for(int j=0;j<ingrSeperatorList.size();j++){
                    ingrSeperatorList.set(j,ingrSeperatorList.get(j)*5);
                }
            }
        }

    //}
    }//end converter

    /**
     * Gets serving size input from user and then adjusts seperated ingredinets accordingly
     */
    public static void multiply() throws Exception{

        for(int j=0;j<ingrSeperatorList.size();j++){
            ingrSeperatorList.set(j,ingrSeperatorList.get(j)*250);
        }
    }//end divide
}//end main
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but an observation and suggestion: Your code isn't object-oriented. For an assignment like this, I would expect to see classes, like `Recipe`, `Ingredient`, and `Units`, that work together to solve the problem. If you can separate out responsibilities, it will make your code much easier to read and understand. If you're unable to do that, I would suggest using clearer names for your variables, e.g. `ingrList -> ingredients`, `sc -> scanner`, `ingrSeparatorList -> quantities`. You will find it much easier to debug when you can read your code easily.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. On my next assignment I will definitely take this into account as I realize now its quite a pain to debug with so much going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here, when converting from tablespoons to mililiter:

```
for(int j=0;j<ingrSeperatorList.size();j++){
    ingrSeperatorList.add(ingrSeperatorList.get(j)*15);

}
```

Notice that at every other conversion you use `ingr.SeperatorList.set`, not `.add`. `.add` makes your list grow larger. You're using `.add` while looping through the list, so whenever you use `.add` the list will grow larger and you'll never escape the loop (until you run out of space, that is).

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and solution, it finally works now. However, the issue I have now is I need to merge the arraylist for ingredient quantity's and the list for ingredients and their units. How would I go about doing this, do I create another arraylist and add both?

Comment: Really depends on how you wanna go about things. I would suggest creating a class `Ingredient` that contains a `String` signifying the ingredient name or type, and an `int` signifying quantity. Then loop through both your quantity list and name list, create a new `Ingredient` object representing the information you already have, and add it to an `ArrayList<Ingredient>`. You might also want to store some information about the unit it's referring to. An alternative would be to just store the quantity and name in the same `String`, but that makes unit conversions and other things quite messy.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback again. I have tried your first solution by making a new class and trying use a string and int, but I haven't been able to get much farther with looping through the two lists and adding them to a new list Ingredient. Do you have any other tips that could possibly help.

Comment: Well, the name-list and quantity-list might have the same length, but just to be safe store the minimum of the two lengths in a variable `length`, then do something like this (pseudo-code): `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { ingredients.add(new Ingredient(nameList.get(i), quantityList.get(i)); }`, where ingredients is your list of ingredients, and where (optional) the constructor of Ingredient takes a string and a quantity.

Comment: This is the code I have so far, but it still isn't working:                                  public static void Ingredients() throws Exception{
    int length = IngredientList.size();
    String s;
    int quantity;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){ 
    IngredientList.add(new Ingredients(ingrList.get(i), ingrSeperatorList.get(i)));
    }

Comment: Try setting `length = Math.Min(ingrList.size(), ingrSeperatorList.size());`. When IngredientList is first created it should have a size of 0, so using it as the length won't work.

Comment: Still haven't gotten it to work. My code is getting more messed up now as I try to manipulate things more.

Comment: Does it compile and does it run? I recommend you open up a new question.